# Merge values of objects with same keys into an array using lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have an array of objects which looks like this:

```
const childrens = [
    { orderName: "#1004" },
    { orderName: "#1006" },
    { orderName: "#1007" },
    { orderName: "#1005" },
    { deliveryDate: "25-25-25" },
    { signature: "xq" },
  ];
```

I want this to be converted into object and have values of same keys as an array of values like this

```
{
  orderName: [ '#1004', '#1006', '#1007', '#1005' ],
  deliveryDate: [ '25-25-25' ],
  signature: [ 'xq' ]
}
```

The way i'm doing this right now is by using a reduce function like this

```
_.reduce(
    childrens,
    (acc, cur) => {
      const pairs = _.chain(cur).toPairs().flatten().value();

      if (acc[pairs[0]] === undefined) {
        acc[pairs[0]] = [pairs[1]];
      } else {
        acc[pairs[0]].push(pairs[1]);
      }

      return acc;
    },
    {},
  );
```

I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way using built-in lodash functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `_.mergeWith()` with array spread. When merging 2 values, check if the 1st (`a`) is still `undefined` (the empty object), if so return the 2nd item wrapped in an array, if it exists, use array spread to concat them:

```js
const children = [{"orderName":"#1004"},{"orderName":"#1006"},{"orderName":"#1007"},{"orderName":"#1005"},{"deliveryDate":"25-25-25"},{"signature":"xq"}];

const result = _.mergeWith({}, ...children, (a, b) => 
  _.isUndefined(a) ? [b] : [...a, b]
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! this was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: can you tell me how lodash magically assigns key to the relating values? i tried to read about this mergeWith function in the docs but didn't understand how.

I tried logging values of a and b inside the mergeWith function and this is what i got, the thing i don't understand is how they were linked to correct keys...

```
{ a: undefined, b: '#1004' }
{ a: [ '#1004' ], b: '#1006' }
{ a: [ '#1004', '#1006' ], b: '#1007' }
{ a: [ '#1004', '#1006', '#1007' ], b: '#1005' }
{ a: undefined, b: '25-25-25' }
{ a: undefined, b: 'mk' }
```

Comment: The `_.mergeWith()` customizer is called when merging the values of each key. You can see the parameters pass to the customizer (`(objValue, srcValue, key, object, source, stack)`), and the 3rd one is the key. Essentially it does when the vanilla answers for this question do, it iterates the items, iterates the keys of the current item, ands the relevant value of each key to the end object current values. It just use the customizer to decide how to handle each value.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use lodash, you can do like below.

```js
const children = [
  { orderName: "#1004" },
  { orderName: "#1006" },
  { orderName: "#1007" },
  { orderName: "#1005" },
  { deliveryDate: "25-25-25" },
  { signature: "xq" },
];

const output = children.reduce((a, b) => {
  const key = Object.keys(b)[0];
  if (!a[key]) {
    a[key] = [b[key]];
  } else {
    a[key].push(b[key]);
  }
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work on modern JS platforms (added bonus, you don't need lodash to use `reduce`). Essentially:

- loop over each item in `childrens`
- get the key(s) for that object
- loop over the key(s)

  - if result doesn't have that key set it to an empty array
  - push the value for the key to the relevant array on the result

```
const desiredOutput = childrens.reduce(
  (acc, current) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(current);
    keys.forEach(key => {
      if (!acc[key]) {
        acc[key] = [];
      }
      acc[key].push(current[key]);
    });
    return acc;
  },
  {}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the result using vanilla JS using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
(acc[prop] = acc[prop] ?? []).push(value);
```

```js
const childrens = [
  { orderName: "#1004" },
  { orderName: "#1006" },
  { orderName: "#1007" },
  { orderName: "#1005" },
  { deliveryDate: "25-25-25" },
  { signature: "xq" },
];

const result = childrens.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [[prop, value]] = Object.entries(curr);
  (acc[prop] = acc[prop] ?? []).push(value);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```